# How to override case sensitivity in IDictionary<string,string>

Tags: c#

I have dictionary entries that are read to a `Dictionary <string,string> myDict=null;`

The entries are like:

```
"user","Anthony"
"lastLogin","May 10 2010 20:43"
```

How would I retrieve `lastLogin`  with lowercase key  `myDict["lastlogin"]` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A constructor for `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` takes a comparer object. You simply need to pass whatever comparer you want to it.

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Of course, you may want to pass things like `CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` or `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` depending on your need.

Answer (score 0):

Pass an `IEqualityComparer<string>` into the `Dictionary` constructor, e.g., `StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`.